# SharpSSH invalid privatekey

Tags: c#, sftp, private-key, sharpssh

I use SharpSSH to connect to a stfp-server.

This for I need to add a privatekey-file like this:

```
sftp.AddIdentityFile(KeyFilePath);
```

But this throws an exception:

```
invaid privatekey: C:\KeyFile\privatekey_2.ppk
```

The file was created with puttygen and works with filezilla.
The privatekey-type doesn't matter (SSH-1 RSA, SSH-2 RSA, SSH-2 DSA). Everytime the same result.

Do you know how to handle this problem?

Comment: I'm not fond of your specific library but the Putty key format is just their own format. Did you try by using a normal keyfile generated with __ssh-keygen__?

Comment: You also have the option to export the key in the standard format from puttygen, in `Conversions->Export OpenSSH Key`

Comment: Just a note - there's no "standard" format for SSH keys - different software uses different formats. OpenSSH format is one of the popular ones, but not a standard, as it's not defined in any standard specification.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to convert your key to OpenSSH Format:

Use PuttyGen to generate and convert the key (Conversion -> export OpenSSH Key)