# Issue with streaming private key using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, azure, ssh, ssh.net

I'm using Renci.SshNet library and have it working with using a username and private key. I can get the private key to open fine when it is read from a file or file stream, but it fails during a memory stream.

This works:

```
var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\myfile.ppk");
```

This works:

```
var f = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile.ppk", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(f);
```

These fail with "Invalid Private Key".

```
var s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(variablename));
//No carriage returns
var s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- <snip>"));
//Include carriage returns
var s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- <snip>"));
```

I even tried the stream position as found on SO:

```
private Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

I was at first thinking the Renci library had a bug with the `Stream`, but obviously the file stream works. I plan on hosting the key in string format in an azure storage table, but am open to other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I generated my private key file with SSH by using [PuTTYgen](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/generating-rsa-keys-with-ssh-puttygen/) and converted my key to OpenSSH format by referring to this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449525/sharpssh-invalid-privatekey). Based on the code you provided about using `MemoryStream`, I could make it work as expected on my side, you could refer to it:

```
var f = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(f, "{password}");
```

**Note:** I assumed that the string content of your private key which passed to `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is in the incorrect format. To isolate this cause, you could try to save your loaded `MemoryStream` to a file as following code and compare it with `C:\myfile.ppk`.

```
memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

> I plan on hosting the key in string format in an azure storage table, but am open to other ideas

As I known, for web applications hosted on Azure Web App, you could leverage [app settings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) to store the key-value pairs which could be automatically loaded and overridden the existing appsettings within your web.config file at run-time.

Also, you could leverage [Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to store your private key file in private and retrieve it as follows:

```
using(var ms=new MemoryStream())
{
   cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
   var pk = new PrivateKeyFile(ms, "{password}"); 
}
```

**Note:** You could follow the "Encrypting blob data" section in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to encrypt your blob data both on client and server side.

Additionally, you could leverage [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis) to store your private key. More details, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started) for getting started with Azure Key Vault.

Comment: I think I was so blinded by this, your elementary debug thing helped -- my head was so deep in the problem I forgot the basic debug details. For some reason the copy/paste from Notepad++ to Azure table inserted some errant characters into it -- no idea. Put spaces around the "/" char, probably some type of azure escape. I copied the string back from azure to Visual Studio and bam!

But the bigger part I think you're right and I like your solution better to store the whole file in a BLOB and stream it from there, and not worry about the formatting. Thanks for that idea, I'm going with that.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer helped me.  I had the exact same problem where reading directly from a file worked but could not get a memorystream to work.  It would give the error "invalid private key" every time.

The way I was reading the file into the memory steam was like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ReadSSHKeyFromDatabase();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile pkf = new Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile(ms, Password);
```

However I got it to work by changing it to this:

```
byte[] bytes = ReadSSHKeyFromDatabase();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile pkf = new Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile(ms, Password);
```